How to use database methods in grails spock specification tests?
I am going to test some classes test using specification test with spock.
Some methods uses Domain.list() and it not available via light specification test.
Of course I could replace Domain.list() with mock grobal replace.
But it disables other Domain static methods. How to change only one static domain method and stay others?
I used mocking this way:
GroovyMock(Domain,global: true)
Domain.list() >> [ domain1, domain2 ]


Have you tried a GroovySpy?
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q78963473

import spock.lang.Specification

class MockSingleStaticMethodTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    GroovySpy(Domain, global: true)
    Domain.list() >> ['domain1', 'domain2']

    expect:
    Domain.list() == ['domain1', 'domain2']
    Domain.doSomething() == 'result'
  }
}

class Domain {
  static List list() {
    println 'listing'
    ['one', 'two', 'three']
  }

  static String doSomething() {
    println 'doing something'
    'result'
  }
}

Try it in the Groovy Web Console.
